# Записать элементы массива с шагом и вычислить их сумму

Tags: javascript, массивы

Задание - написать 2 функции: первая принимает диапазон с шагом и записывает числа из диапазона в массив, вторая - принимает этот массив на вход и подсчитывает сумму его элементов. Собственно, до истины я почти докопался, но почему-то в первой функции происходит баг и при диапазоне (1, 10) я получаю на единицу больше. Откуда берется эта ошибка?
P.S. если шаг не задан, то дефолтный шаг = 1

```
//my realization
const range = (start, end, step) => {
  const list = [];
  if (step === undefined) {
    for (let i = start; i <= end; i++) {
      list.push(i);
    };
  };
  for (let i = start; i < end; i += step) {
    list.push(i);
  };
  return list;
};


const sum = list => {
  let result = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    result += list[i];
  };
  return result;
};

console.log(range(1, 10));   // [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1] - лишняя единица!
console.log(range(1, 10, 2));   // [1,3,5,7,9]
console.log(sum(range(1, 10)));  // 56 - функция суммы работает правильно, но проблема все та же
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const range = (start, end, step) => {
  const list = [];
  if (step === undefined)
    step = 1;
  for (let i = start; i <= end; i += step)
    list.push(i);
  return list;
};

const sum = list => {
  let result = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    result += list[i];
  };
  return result;
};

console.log(range(1, 10));   // [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1] - лишняя единица!
console.log(range(1, 10, 2));   // [1,3,5,7,9]
console.log(sum(range(1, 10)));  // 55
```

Comment: Мда, аж стыдно за такую ошибку. Спасибо за ответ